# Math symbol for approximation of probability distribution by arbitrary function?

Tags: probability, functions

I want to use a symbol between two functions;

$$p\text{ (symbol) }f$$

such that $p$ is a probability function and $\text{(symbol)}$ implies: we do not have access to $p$ but we approximate it with a function $f$ which is not a probability function (i.e. although it produces values between $0$ and $1$, its values do not sum up to $1$). Any ideas?

Comment: Why dont you normalize $f$ and denote it as $f^*$ and after that name it as aaproximately $\approx$?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use $\stackrel{*}{\sim}$.  The tilde is usually used in calculus to say one function behaves like another (such as when doing infinite series). In most cases, as long as you are clear to define your symbols to the reader and be consistent, it usually is not a problem.

Edit: added a * above tilde to not confuse be confused with $X \sim P$ which is read as $X$ is distributed as $P$, as noted by Memming in the comments.

Comment: I will check this one, sorry I can't vote up since I am a newbie.

Comment: $X \sim P$ is often used in probability to denote that $X$ is distributed as $P$, so it may be confusing to use tilde.

Comment: @Memming, hmm, did not know that. I'm just taking my first 400-level stats course this semester, so I will come across this soon I imagine. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just use the typical "approximation" symbol ≈ to denote this? This symbol means "approximately", but it can also mean "asymptotic to".

Using unicode: &asymp; produces ≈.

Using latex: \approx produces $\approx$.

Comment: Regarding my problem statement, I am not sure if approximation symbol is adequate.

Comment: Why not? Approximation is precisely what you are doing, after all. If they were exact in meaning and measure we would not use the approximation symbol but the equality symbol.

Comment: The notation `&asymp;` is HTML, not Unicode.

Comment: OMG, vonbrand. Does it really matter?  And no, its unicode. But since it matters so darn much to this question...

Comment: Pretentiousness. Ongoing problem. Take a good, reasonable answer and some doucher has to poke holes in it.  Youre not wrong, but let me tell you how youre wrong anyway to help me with my own ego.